# In spring , How to continue the request from the Controller for loop after transactional rollback happened for one iteration

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, rollback, transactional

Request is closing after any rollback happened in the service layer.It is not continuing from the controller.

ex:

```
public Class UserController {
 @Autowired
 UserService userService;
 createUserList(List < User > list) {
  try {
  RespObj obj=new RespObj();
   List < Obj > errorList = new ArrayList();
   for (User user: list) {
    Object obj = userService.createUser(user);
    errorList.add(obj);
   }
   //return success response along with any errorlist
   obj.setStatus(200);
   obj.setObj(errorList);
   return obj;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   //returning error response 
   obj.setStatus(400);
   obj.setObj(e.getMessage());
   return obj; 
  }
 }
}
```

//UserServiceImpl

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
 @Transactional
 Object createUser(user) {
  try {
   dao.saveUser(user);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   //create error pojo 
  }
  // return error pojo if any
 }
}
```

In above code if any one user creation is fails, roll back is happening for that user alone and after that remaining user objects are not processing.

Requirement is :leave the one failed and Need to process the remaining user objects which were not processed .

Comment: can you post code inside `catch` block inside controller ?

Comment: Hi Jayesh, code added .Please verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like so to process all users, add errors to errorList.

```
RespObj obj=new RespObj();
List < Obj > errorList = new ArrayList();
for (User user: list) {
 User user = new Object;
 try {
     user = userService.createUser(user);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      obj.setMessage(e.getMessage());
      obj.setStatus(400);
      errorList.add(obj);
     }
   }
   obj.setStatus(200);
   obj.setErrorList(errorList);
   return obj;
 }
```

Comment: I understood the issue.My code creating org.hibernate.exception.DataException exception in service  layer  which was catched there.But after that system generating   org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException which was not handled/catched  anywhere .So the loop was ending abruptly.With above code I can catch the TransactionSystemException in controller and continue with the other items in the loop.Thanks.Is there any way I Can catch this exception there itself in service layer,whenever the transaction rollback happend?

Answer (score 0):

If you service is transactional and you call it in a loop, you have to catch the exception inside the loop. 
This is a general problem with request that processed more than one item. Should all items be rejected or do you collect the items that failed....

Comment: only the ones which were failed and rolled back. Remaining should continue and finish the save.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't seems to have the problem you described because:

1. You have catch the exception and handled it in the createUser method, and the Exception won't be propagated to the Controller. Controller will continue to process the next one.
2. Transactional is annotated in Service method , which is correct. Whenever the service method returned to controller and the transaction is ended and a new one will be created when processing next user.

Your described problem seems that you didn't handle the exception inside the service.

Another possibility is that you have another exception inside the catch clause or return statement.